# How to create submenus in off canvas in Foundation 6

Tags: zurb-foundation-6, off-canvas-menu

How can I create submenus in off canvas in Foundation 6?

I found this handy building [block](http://zurb.com/building-blocks/top-bar-with-off-canvas),
but it doesn't feature submenus in the LHS off-canvas menu.

I'd like a slide-in submenu like this [one](http://bit.ly/1VSShig) (this is Foundation 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for Foundation 6's Drilldown menu. See link below and code snippet from page.

```
<ul class="vertical menu" data-drilldown>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/drilldown-menu.html

Comment: Thanks that's it!! This submenu slides in from the right is there a way to make it slide in from the left?